# Control engineering: how to design a system for desired impulse response

Tags: control, transient, bode-plot, nyquist-plot, root-locus

I've designed a system to get a desirable step response. However, I think the impulse response of my system is more important.

There are many methods for designing a system for transient response specifications related to the step response. I was wondering, is there similar material for a desirable impulse response?

Are there methods for shaping the bode plot, Nyquist plot or root locus of a system to get a desirable impulse response?

Comment: Since one defines the other completely (at least for linear systems, which you're implicitly asking about), there's no design freedom left; you've defined the impulse response by defining the step response. The former is the derivative of the latter. So, if you have a method to design one with a step response like you want it to be, just take the antiderivative of the impulse response you want, design your system, done.

Comment: anyways, your question is very broad, and you'll find that in most signals and systems books, *most* consideration of the time domain actually are usually more concerned with the impulse response. You'll really just have to read on!